# How to confirm that I am in the center of the path of totality for the Solar Eclipse of April 08 2024 using GPS or Android/Iphone App?

Tags: amateur-observing, solar-eclipse, prediction

There is going to be a [Solar Eclipse on April 08 2024](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_eclipse_of_April_8,_2024).

I will need to travel to be in path of totality from California/Florida. I am trying to get a Android or iPhone App that can tell me if i have reached to a location where I can experience totality for at least one minute.

Comment: The info here should be helpful:  https://eclipsewise.com/solar/SEprime/2001-2100/SE2024Apr08Tprime.html & https://eclipsewise.com/solar/SEgmapx/2001-2100/SE2024Apr08Tgmapx.html

Comment: This is a web based map:
https://www.celestialprogramming.com/apps/SolarEclipseViewer/viewer.html

Answer (score 4):

This app should do the trick https://www.space.com/totality-app-big-kid-science-april-total-solar-eclipse-2024 . I tested it on my Amazon Fire tablet and it gives you all the details for any point you tap on the map. You can zoom it up as close as you like. I have not been able to test the GPS functionality though as my tablet does not support it. You can also use [this website](http://xjubier.free.fr/en/site_pages/solar_eclipses/xSE_GoogleMap3.php?Ecl=%2020240408) which does pretty much the same (without the GPS). The times there seem to be given as UT by default, but you can toggle this with local time with the timezone tool button on the left.

Note that either of those require an internet connection though to download the maps (both of them use Google maps internally). Also, the second suggestion (and some others you can find on the web) is not optimized for mobile devices (the display is not very good and sluggish as well), so I would definitely go for the app, which runs quite smoothly.